# Require new login for each page view

Tags: python, authentication, flask

I am currently using code found here:

http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/8/

And I decorate my function accordingly to have the admin authenticate when requesting a specific admin page. However, instead of requiring the admin to keep authenticating each time they admin page, I noticed that it somehow keeps track of the session and no longer requires authentication after successfully authenticating once. Is there some way to force flask to re-authenticate every time an admin requests the given decorated admin page?

Comment: Why would you want anyone to re-login in for every page view?

Comment: No, you've misunderstood. Think of it as an admin page for admins. Just a single page requires authentication to access something that requires elevated privileges. All other pages do not require authentication

Comment: take a look at the answer I provide, I believe this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Using the included snippet, there is no good way to force a user to log in every time they request the given page.

This is because that snippet is using HTTP Basic Auth and there is no good way to ask the browser to stop sending that header.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for can be done with a custom decorator. You can use the **sample** below. Note that your case will be different, but you can use this as a guide.

```
from web import app, has_role

@app.route("/admin/my_page")
@login_required
@has_role(role="admin")
def admin_my_page():
    //do stuff
```

Then, in your project init, or an include file you can add the following:

```
def has_role(role=None):
    def _initial_decorator(view_func):
        def _decorator(*args, **kwargs):
            response = view_func(*args, **kwargs)
            if g.user.user_level != role:
                from flask import redirect, url_for

                return redirect(url_for("no_access"))
            return response

        return wraps(view_func)(_decorator)

    return _initial_decorator
```

This should at lease give you an idea of how to create a custom decorator, and then check for role permissions. You can expand this to however you need. You can put engine logic, or other checks to fit your project.

Comment: I don't see where the authentication comes into your code. Furthermore, how to force the browser to forget the authentication in the header.

Comment: @slaw The authentication comes with the has_role. Basically you check to see if the user that is already logged in has a specific role. If you are talking about an entire separate login page, then you can still use the above code, but instead of checking for roles, you can check for a session variable, and then redirect to a LoginManager: https://flask-login.readthedocs.io/en/latest/